# C# SourceGenerators and Dependency Injection

Tags: dependency-injection

Playing with the new .NET 5 ISourceGenerators.

From what I understand, the class that implements ISourceGenerator must have a zero-parameter contructor.

Are there any plans to allow constructor DI?

Right now I am instantiating a ServiceCollection and ServiceProvider instance in a default instance constructor.

Comment: Considering that a Source Generator runs at compile time, whereas Dependency Injection is applied when the application runs, how would it help for an `ISourceGenerator` implementation to accept constructor arguments?

Answer (score 0):

closing this out... i have accepted that DI is not the way to go...for now